A variable I'm pulling out of the query params does not reflect in the html
constructor(private router: Router
    , private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) 
  {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.rootRoute(this.route))
  ).subscribe((route: ActivatedRoute) => {
    let tempusSuccessResponse = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('TRANSUCCESS');
    let val = tempusSuccessResponse ? tempusSuccessResponse.toUpperCase() === 'TRUE' : false
    this.creditCardSubmitSuccess = val;
    if (val) {
      let tempusTokenResponse = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('REPTOKEN');
      let val1 = tempusTokenResponse ? tempusTokenResponse : '';
      this.creditCardToken = val1;
    }
    this.emitter.next(val)
    alert(this.creditCardSubmitSuccess + ' ' + this.creditCardToken);
  });
  }

<div class="row">
  <h2>{{creditCardToken}}</h2>
  <h2>{{creditCardSubmitSuccess}}</h2>
  <div *ngIf="creditCardSubmitSuccess">
    <label>Credit card successfully integrated</label>
  </div>
</div>

I have the above code where I'm pulling query params out of the router. I'm trying to set a boolean value in the front end based on what I get back out of the query params. I can succesfully make the call and alert the creditCardSubmitSuccess and see that I do indeed get back a true response along with a token. I have the creditCardSubmitSuccess variable tied to an *ngif in the html that always displays false. I can't get it to update.
I have tried using a BehaviorSubject and Observables. I have also tried messing with ChangeDetectorRef. I'm not having any luck.
EDIT: Added the html. The h2s are just for testing purposes to see if values are coming across.

please share the HTML also!

Can you try removing this. from the if statement?

@AntonThomas good shout but no luck.

What does <h2>{{creditCardSubmitSuccess}}</h2> render?

It shows false even though the alert shows true.

Does the other property <h2>{{creditCardToken}}</h2> render the same value that you see in the alert box?

It just displays the default value set which is an empty string. It does not render the same value that I see in the alert box

Hi @COLEplusTEN, I faced this kind of problem, could you please set the flag on the  main div and load when you have router.events response successfully in the subscribe section.

if you want more detail, let me know I am hear to help you.

Ok I moved the flag but no luck. What exactly do you mean by "load when you have router.events response"

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-events?file=src%2Fmain.ts. Check where it differs from your code

I moved the router.events.pipe out of the constructor and into ngoninit and now the subscribe is never hit

@COLEplusTEN Please create a minimal app on Stackblitz that reproduces the problem. There must be something that we don't see that is causing it.
